# Trying to use I2C ITs with HAL Functions

Tags: stm32, i2c, interrupts, hal-library

**Hardware :**
STM32L452RET6

**Software :**
STM32CubeFW_L4 v1.17

**My problem :**
After using I2C with standard polling functions, i would like to use IT Functions to optimize my firmware. I try to work with *HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_IT* & *HAL_I2C_Master_Receive_IT* but my firmware stay blocked in the *I2C1_EV_IRQHandler* :

```
void HAL_I2C_EV_IRQHandler(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
{
  /* Get current IT Flags and IT sources value */
  uint32_t itflags   = READ_REG(hi2c->Instance->ISR);
  uint32_t itsources = READ_REG(hi2c->Instance->CR1);

  /* I2C events treatment -------------------------------------*/
  if (hi2c->XferISR != NULL)
  {
    hi2c->XferISR(hi2c, itflags, itsources);
  }
}
```

The IT flags seems not to be cleared and the hi2c->XferISR register seems to be NULL :
[image]

[image]

**Edit 1 :**
Some additional informations : The following functions are never called.

```
void HAL_I2C_MasterTxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)

void HAL_I2C_MasterRxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)

void HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
```

I tried to clear I2C_FLAG_TXE & I2C_FLAG_TXIS but it's seems not possible.

**Edit 2 :** To answer some questions in comment :

The init code is well passed :

```
Status I2C_Init(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
{
    // Peripheral Clock Enable
    __HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE();

    hi2c->Instance = I2C1;
    hi2c->Init.Timing = 0x10909CEC;
    hi2c->Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
    hi2c->Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
    hi2c->Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
    hi2c->Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
    hi2c->Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
    hi2c->Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
    hi2c->Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;

    // Interrupts Activation
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(I2C1_EV_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(I2C1_EV_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(I2C1_ER_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(I2C1_ER_IRQn);

    if (HAL_I2C_Init(hi2c) != HAL_OK)
    {
        return STATUS_ERROR;
    }

    return STATUS_OK;
}
```

There is no bus activity on scope.

Comment: How have you initialized the I2C? Did you write init code yourself or did you let CubeIDE/CubeMX generate initial code for you?

Comment: Is the slave responding correct?

Comment: @jay That would be unknown, since the ISR is null, so the code would not even go that far to know if any slave is on the bus.

Comment: TXE sounds like TX empty. Meantime TXIS is used for slave mode. Read the [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00151940-stm32l41xxx-42xxx-43xxx-44xxx-45xxx-46xxx-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

Comment: p1127, I2C_TXDR register is not empty. 
p1141, Slave transmitter
A transmit interrupt status (TXIS) is generated when the I2C_TXDR register becomes
empty. An interrupt is generated if the TXIE bit is set in the I2C_CR1 register.
The TXIS bit is cleared when the I2C_TXDR register is written with the next data byte to be
transmitted.

Comment: When i call the HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_IT function, the hi2c->XferISR variable is set to I2C_Master_ISR_IT. It allows the IT to find the linked IT function, in this function there are TXIS bit check & TXDR filling. But when the it is fired, the hi2c->XferISR seems null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the source of my problem :

I have three steps to drive the I2C :

1. My main function drive a peripheral one : **VL53L0X_Init(...);**
2. My peripheral function drive a register one : **I2C_WriteRegister(...);**
3. My register function use **HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_IT(...);**

On the first one : I give a pointer on I2C Structure when it is received i saved this pointer with : **I2C = *hi2c;**

I2C is the global variable contained in the peripheral file : **I2C_HandleTypeDef I2C**.

My error here is to affect the pointer to the variable. The solution is to declare a pointer and to copy the I2C structure pointer to it during the init :

I2C_HandleTypeDef *I2C;

I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c;

**I2C = hi2c;**